# Ember Select default value not working

Tags: ember.js

Just want to the select to render with a default value checked

I have:

```
{{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding=programmers
   optionValuePath="content.id"
   optionLabelPath="content.firstName"
   value=currentProgrammer.id}}

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  programmers: [
    {firstName: "Yehuda", id: 1},
    {firstName: "Tom",    id: 2}
  ],

 currentProgrammer: {id: '2'}
});
```

I'm borrowing code from the api docs, which I haven't had much luck with since much of the sample code is deprecated :/

I have a jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/qefec/1/edit

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `selectionBinding`:

```
{{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding=programmers
   optionValuePath="content.id"
   optionLabelPath="content.firstName"
   selectionBinding="currentProgrammer"}}
```

See http://jsbin.com/dayer/1/